# Setting env varables for entire workflow

Tags: github-actions

I have a step that sets some env vars in job1.  How do i make those env vars available in job2 without having to set them again in job2?
I cannot combine the jobs into one single job because job2 (in my real code) is using a matrix.

```
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, my-Windows-machine ]
    steps:
      - name: set env vars
        run: |
          echo "this_git_ws=$($env:GITHUB_WORKFLOW -replace ' ', '-')" >> $env:GITHUB_ENV      
          echo 'c:\Program Files\Git\bin' | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append
      - name: another step to do something
        shell: cmd
        run: |
          set
          <...other commands...>
  job2:
    needs: job1
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, my-Windows-machine ]
    steps:
      - name: show env vars
        shell: cmd
        run: |
          set
          <...other commands...>
```

I realize that i can set env vars for the entire workflow by defining the env vars in the `env:` block, but i'm not sure of the correct syntax to use for non-static values.

Comment: Otherwise you can find some more information in the [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#passing-values-between-steps-and-jobs-in-a-workflow).

Comment: Thx, @flaxel
Looks like using output vars is the only way to go.